# Read from a continuously growing text file C++ in real time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ifstream

I went through all the answers that were available regarding real-time reading a text file but none seems to work.
In my program 1 have a continuously growing text file being written by a hardware which is giving two coordinates (two columns).
In program 2, I want to read those coordinates in real time and move another hardware to the coordinates that are being written.
The biggest problem is I want to work with shortest possible delay (under 50ms).
I tried notepad++, but its refresh rate is 3 seconds which is too much.
Can anyone tell how can this be done?

Comment: A file may not be the right choice for this. Do you have access to pipes, sockets or other forms of [interprocess communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)?

Comment: I don't think I have access to these. What may be the right choice, if not a text file??

Comment: How is the hardware communicating to the PC?  direct connection (PCI bus)?  External communciations, e.g. USB, RS232, Parallel, Ethernet, etc?

Comment: Also worth updating the question with the target operating system. Someone around here will be familiar with whatever you are using and can suggest options.

Comment: For example, if you are running on Windows, a mailslot ([link to example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365785(v=vs.85).aspx)) can be a really simple, relatively low overhead way to pass a small message quickly.

Comment: Hardware is communicating via USB.

Comment: I am using windows 10, 64 bit

Comment: Do you control the program reading the hardware and writing the file? Hmmm Bad wording.  By control, I mean did you write the program or have input into how it functions? Can you replace the file with a different communication method?

Answer (score 1):

Your fastest response is to either poll (read the hardware) directly or to have the hardware create an event (interrupt) that calls your program.

Writing to a file takes time.  The OS has to find space on the hard drive, write to the hard drive; and not to mention the time required to ramp up the motors to spin the hard drive.

Writing to memory is a lot quicker.  A more efficient method is for the H/W to write to memory rather than a file.  Alternately, a memory mapped file or RAM drive will be the next best option.

Also remember that Windows is not a real-time operating system.  You have other tasks in your system being swapped out and executed.  This takes time away from your "real time" requirements.  You may want to research Windows to see if there is an API that allows your program exclusive access to the processor (or makes your program a very high priority).

Research "Windows Drivers" to write code that can service your H/W and perform activities in real time.

Comment: My Biggest problem is that I need to refresh my notepad file. And my requirement is soon as I change the data in the txt file, it should appear on the console window.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this:

```
int main()
```

{
    std::ifstream ifs("file.txt");

```
if (ifs.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    while (true)
    {
        while (std::getline(ifs, line)) std::cout << line << "\n";
        if (!ifs.eof()) break; 
        ifs.clear();


    }
}

return 0;
```

}

But it reads till the end and when i add more values to my text file, it doesn't read that. But when I refresh my file, I get the o/p on the console.

I have also tried using tellg and seekg but that also doesn't help.